# Java get x and y coordinates

Tags: java, location, cell

i'm trying to make a Minesweeper game.but i'm a little bit confused how to get the x and y coordinators for each cell in the game in order to draw an image for each cell. This code draw only the first cell which has the location (0,0). how can i get a reference to the other cells ?
and this is my code:

```
    public  class Cell {
     private int row, col;
     private int ulx, uly, w, h;
     private boolean marked, covered, mined;
     private int adjcount;

     private Cell(int r, int c) {
        marked=false;
        covered=true;
        mined=false;
        row=r;
        col=c;
        w=h=16;
        adjcount=0;
     }

     public int getX(){
         return ulx;     
     }

     public int getY(){
         return uly;     
     }

     public boolean getMarked() {
        return marked;
     }

     public void setMarked(boolean value) {
        marked=value;
     }

     public boolean getCovered() {
        return covered;
     }

     public void setCovered(boolean value) {
        covered=value;
     }

     public boolean getMined() {
        return mined;
     }

     public void setMined(boolean value) {
        mined=value;
     }

     public void setAdjCount(int count) {
        adjcount = count;
     }

     public int getAdjCount() {
        return adjcount;
     }
```

and here is where i draw each cell in the game

```
  if (getCovered() == true && getMarked () == false) {    // gray rectangle
           g.drawImage(gRec,getX(),getY(),w,h,null);

        }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, you may want to set a constant like the width and height on a `manager` of these cells, instead in all cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't assign `ulx` and `uly` anywhere. You may put the following code at the end of the constructor:

```
ulx = col * w;
uly = row * h;
```